# how to open ubuntu on command line . I got it installed in wsl but it won't open when I type Ubuntu. what is the command to get it to open?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

how to open ubuntu on command line . I got it installed in win 11 but it won't open when I type Ubuntu. what is the command to get it to open?

Comment: [This Microsoft resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands) might be helpful. However, this is a Microsoft support issue, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

**1. Ensure Ubuntu is installed**

It seems possible that you have installed WSL, but not Ubuntu. Make sure it is installed with:

```
wsl --list
```

This should print a list of the distros you have installed, and Ubuntu should show up. Otherwise, install it with:

```
wsl --install Ubuntu
```

**2. Run Ubuntu**

Easiest way is to run the launcher:

```
ubuntu.exe
```

You can also run it with the WSL executable:

```
wsl -d Ubuntu
```